# How to reference Bamboo artifacts in scripts

Tags: bamboo, bamboo-artifacts

I know how to export/share an artifact from one stage/job to another.   In my job configuration, I can say "place artifact 'My artifact' in into destination directory 'foo'"  That works and all, but in my job, I'm calling a script where I want to pass that artifact as a parameter.   How can I tell what that artifact's name is?  I can't pass `foo/*` as an argument to the task Script as the `*` is literally passed instead of shell expanded, even if I mark the `Interpreter` as `Shell`.

It seems that there should be some sort of `${bamboo.artifact}` type of variable that I could pass, but I was unable to locate something.  I know the Bamboo name of the artifact, so it seems like there should be a way to know exactly what the variable name is without having to resort to shell wildcarding hacks.

I looked at https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/sharing-artifacts-359400060.html#Sharingartifacts-Sharingartifactsbetweenjobs and https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo0610/bamboo-variables-980469487.html

Comment: There's no bamboo var that will give you a list of the files which an artifact brings in. Pass the folder where you download your artifact files to the script. Using `*` in the script task's args won't work: Bamboo simply doesn't use shell when calling your script (but java, I presume).